# Blazor WASM Cookie consent trigger javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Within a blazor app we have a cookie consent banner. On accepting this we wish to trigger some javascript only if they accepted. We tried putting it within the component but this isn't allowed and says to do it on index.html but this doesn't know about the response to the cookie consent. Is it possible to do somehow?

Comment: You can link to the actual JS file in `index.html` and call whatever function you want using JS interop from your component.  Though I'd be curious why it needs to be in javascript at all.

Comment: Well you're able to load JavaScript files inside your components if wanted, at least for .NET 6 (you didn't specify a specific version, so..). Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules). There might also be an option to use normal `@onclick="NameOfC#MethodForPressedOkButton"` onclick event of blazor of success button. Usually you can mostly ignore JS stuff with Blazor ;)

Comment: The script we want to trigger is a google tag manager script but only if the user has accepted tracking cookies. Until they do, we don’t want anything from gtm on the page.